# How to build collapsible/expandable table rows like news.google.com

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, mustache

I am building a webpage to show some articles and related article. I want to build something similar to what you see on news.google.com

I strongly feel there is a better way to do it than what I am doing, so coming here for suggestions.

Currently my html code is something like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><a href="article.htm">{{ArticleHeading}}</a> <br/> {{ArticleSynopsis}}</td>
  <td>{{ArticleSource}}</td>
  <td>{{ArticleDate}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I also have color change of row when mouse hovers.

```
.table-hover  {
    background-color:#FFE292;
    border:1px solid #DD9946;
    color:#000000;
}
```

What I want and cannot figure out how to do it:

**1.** When user clicks on a row anywhere (not just headline), the table should expand to show another sub-table with related articles.

**2.** If possible hovering effect is stopped once table is expanded.

I have already seen accordion example from http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html

That doesn't meet my requirements.

Please let me know if something is not clear or scope of this question is very broad. I would love to address those concern of yours.

Comment: something along [these](http://girlswhogeek.com/tutorials/2007/show-and-hide-elements-with-javascript) lines?

Comment: i would get started learning jQuery if I were you, with jQuery you can do all you've outlined and more :) when your requirements become this broad you are forced to start writing custom code.

Comment: Thanks!. I know basic jQuery. Is there any good/quick tutorial for things I want to achieve. Or, any code example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something which would help me achieve news.google.com look
http://jqueryui.com/addClass/

Also this page has very nice learning resource for jQuery beginners like me.

http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page